# How configure two dockers (1-apache+mod_fcgi 2-php-fpm+phpmyadmin)

Tags: docker, apache, fpm

I tried to use this set of dockers, but to no avail.

On the internet, I only find use cases with docker: nginx + phpmyadmin (php-fpm)

If someone can help me with this configuration, how can I configure 2 dockers

1. apache
2. php-fpm + phpMyAdmin

I tried to use these settings for vhost.conf of apache

```
PHP_FPM_CONTAINER=myDockerPhpMyAdmin:9000

<FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler proxy:fcgi://${PHP_FPM_CONTAINER}
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
PHP_FPM_CONTAINER=myDockerPhpMyAdmin:9000

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    Options +ExecCGI
    FcgidConnectTimeout 20
    AddType  application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    ProxyPassMatch ^/${PHP_FPM_CONTEXT}/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://${PHP_FPM_CONTAINER}/\$1"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what I had here https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/350

The main problems I faced with phpmyadmin docker image were:

- it seems to be missconfigured and only serve *.php files by default
- it serves everything as text/html

My solution was:

For the vhost

```
        <VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
            ServerName phpmyadmin.local.lan
            ProxyPreserveHost on
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [P,QSA,L]
            ProxyPass / "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/"
            ProxyPassReverse / "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/"
            <LocationMatch "^/.*\.css">
                    Header set Content-type "text/css"
            </LocationMatch>
            <LocationMatch "^/.*\.js">
                    Header set Content-type "text/javascript"
            </LocationMatch>
        </VirtualHost>
```

For the docker compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'mariadb:10.5.13'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'mariadb'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    volumes:
      - './volumes/mariadb/varlibmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  phpmyadmin:
    image: 'phpmyadmin:5.1.1-fpm-alpine'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'phpmyadmin'
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9000:9000
    volumes:
      - './volumes/phpmyadmin/disablesecurity.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/disablesecurity.conf'
    environment:
      HIDE_PHP_VERSION: "true"
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: https://phpmyadmin.local.lan/
    depends_on:
      - "mariadb"
```

Where ./volumes/phpmyadmin/disablesecurity.conf is

```
[www]
security.limit_extensions =
```